# Scala check type of generics

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, scala-2.10, type-erasure

How do I do something like this in Scala?

```
case class Foo[A](x: A) {

  def get[T]: Option[T] = x match {
    case x: T => Some(x)    // if x is of type T i.e. T =:= A
    case _ => None
  }
}

val test = Foo("hi")
assert(test.get[Int] == None)
assert(test.get[String] == Some("hi"))
```

I tried this and ran into some weird time inference failure:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success}
import reflect._

case class Foo[A](x: A) extends Dynamic {

  def get[T: ClassTag]: Option[T] = Try(x.asInstanceOf[T]) match {
    case Success(r) => Some(r) 
    case _ => None
  }
}

object Foo extends App {
  val test = Foo("hi")
  val wtf: Option[Int] = test.get[Int]
  assert(wtf.isInstanceOf[Option[String]])
  assert(wtf == Some("hi"))     // how????
  // val wtf2: Option[String] = wtf  // does not compile even if above assert passes!!
}
```

Comment: Look at the warning when you compile this with the `-unchecked` flag: `scala> case class Foo[A](x: A) {
     | 
     |   def get[T]: Option[T] = x match {
     |     case x: T => Some(x)    // if x is of type T i.e. T =:= A
     |     case _ => None
     |   }
     | }
<console>:10: warning: abstract type T in type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
           case x: T => Some(x)    // if x is of type T i.e. T =:= A`. Then see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3789230/2197460. Not an answer, but a start.

Comment: The link you posted has the author asking about the generic `T` case at the end of the question

Comment: s/time/type.  Or, s/work/sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely a dupe, but hastily:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import reflect._
case class Foo[A](x: A) {

  def get[T: ClassTag]: Option[T] = x match {
    case x: T => Some(x)    // if x is of type T i.e. T =:= A
    case _ => None
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import reflect._
defined class Foo

scala> val test = Foo("hi")
test: Foo[String] = Foo(hi)

scala> test.get[Int]
res0: Option[Int] = None

scala> test.get[String]
res1: Option[String] = Some(hi)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can throw out the get:

```
case class Foo[A](x: A)
Seq(Foo("hi"), Foo(1), Foo(2d)).collect { case f @ Foo(x: String) => f }.foreach(println)
```

results in:

```
Foo(hi)
```

And the others are similarly trivial.

Comment: The `get` was just a simplification for StackOverflow - I do need a method with generic type `T` in it.