# Scala type inference fail?

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, scala-2.10, type-erasure

How is this possible:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success}
import reflect._

case class Foo[A](x: A) extends Dynamic {

  def get[T: ClassTag]: Option[T] = Try(x.asInstanceOf[T]) match {
    case Success(r) => Some(r) 
    case _ => None
  }
}

object Foo extends App {
  val test = Foo("hi")
  val wtf: Option[Int] = test.get[Int]
  assert(wtf.isInstanceOf[Option[String]])
  assert(wtf == Some("hi"))     // how????
  // val wtf2: Option[String] = wtf  // does not compile even if above assert passes!!
}
```

Inspired by this question: [Scala check type of generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341339/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Due to type erasure, `wtf.isInstanceOf[Option[String]]` can only check that `wtf` is an instance of `Option`, but not the type parameter. Similarly, `asInstanceOf[T]` is actually a cast to `Object` at the runtime, and so it succeeds. You need to do

   ```
   classTag[T].runtimeClass.cast(x)
   ```

   instead.
2. The compiler can't use the information from asserts passing (you can imagine a compiler which *could*, but Scala simply isn't designed like that). It only knows that the type of `wtf` is `Option[Int]`, so of course you can't initialize an `Option[String]` with it. If you want to get something like that, you need

   ```
   wtf match {
     case wtf2: Option[String] => ...
   }
   ```

   Of course, this doesn't work correctly due to point 1.